# Wifi Driver doesn't work on any Linux Distros

Tags: drivers, wireless, hp, realtek

I have tried 9 Linux OS so far and my Realtek Wifi Driver doesn't work with any of them also I tried each and every single piece of advice I found, 
I'm new to all this, Please HELP!
Here I have attached all needed info for my case without wasting space:
[Screenshot from system tray of deepin Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0VV4.png)

the attachment displays that my system tray has wifi option greyed.

Here's my Wireless_Information:

```
`########## wireless info START ##########`

Report from: 19 Dec 2017 05:18 IST +0530

Booted last: 19 Dec 2017 00:00 IST +0530

Script from: 05 Dec 2017 03:13 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.13.0-19-generic #22-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 11:58:07 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Deepin

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:8329]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b5d5 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 0b05:7782 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

cfg80211              610304  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  3 intel_hid,intel_vbtn,hp_wmi
wmi                    24576  2 wmi_bmof,hp_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto enp0s25
iface enp0s25 inet static
address 192.168.0.16
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
5: enp0s20f0u3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp0s20f0u3' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.42.39/24 brd 192.168.42.255 scope global dynamic enp0s20f0u3
       valid_lft 2513sec preferred_lft 2513sec
    inet6 fe80::fe15:c634:2731:3cf7/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

enp0s20f0u3  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.42.129 dev enp0s20f0u3 proto static metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s20f0u3 scope link metric 1000 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s20f0u3 scope link metric 1002 
192.168.42.0/24 dev enp0s20f0u3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.39 metric 102 

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.0.53

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       738     1  0 04:46 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s20f0u3
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Android
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Android
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 22-Aug-2005
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp0s20f0u3' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/net/enp0s20f0u3
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp0s20f0u3
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 3
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       20398bac-8e14-4ff8-9330-1493acad605d
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{1}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   20398bac-8e14-4ff8-9330-1493acad605d | Wired connection 3
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.42.39/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.42.129
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1002
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.42.39
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.42.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 3150
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 1800
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       expiry = 1513643417
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       host_name = syed-HP-Laptop-15-bs0xx
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       network_number = 192.168.42.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       vendor_encapsulated_options = ANDROID_METERED
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       next_server = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::fe15:c634:2731:3cf7/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eno1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eno1' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0/net/eno1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eno1      no frequency information.

enp0s20f0u3  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eno1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp0s20f0u3  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.13.0-19-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     A5EDD7467E172A70410EBCD
depends:        
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.13.0-19-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf]
options rtl8723be fwlps=0

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[  648.976876] rndis_host 1-3:1.0 enp0s20f0u3: renamed from usb0
[  649.006637] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s20f0u3: link is not ready
[  755.420809] rndis_host 1-3:1.0 enp0s20f0u3: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:14.0-3, RNDIS device
[  848.834006] rndis_host 1-3:1.0 enp0s20f0u3: renamed from usb0
[  848.865726] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s20f0u3: link is not ready

`########## wireless info END ############`
```

Comment: I suggest that you invest in a USB wireless.

Comment: Buying isn't a problem, but can't I make my existing wifi hardware work? I searched but didn't find any reliable solution to my problem and thus came here to finally post about it. And Thnks for answering. I can wait for some months for realtek to release it

Comment: Did you click on the duplicate link and read the answer and the following comments? It says, very clearly, "This device Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device d723 is not supported by Linux yet. It is rtl8723de. There are no vendor drivers either." So, the unambiguous answer to your question, "can't I make my existing wifi hardware work?" is no, you cannot at this time.

Comment: Yeah, I did. and through that link I discovered a person, Larry. W. Finger.. He said realtek didn't sent him the driver software for linux. they will soon, maybe in Q1 2018?? By the way can't the windows driver to makke it work or anything else??

Comment: The mechanism to use the Windows drivers is called *ndiswrapper*. We can certainly try it. Ndiswrapper requires the Windows XP driver files; typically the .sys and .inf files. Please see: `man ndiswrapper`. Do you have or can you find XP drivers for your device? I have seen many attempts to use Windows 7/8/10 drivers and precisely zero success.

Answer (score 0):

There is new information on this device! With a temporary working internet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8723de
sudo dkms build rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414
```

Reboot and let us hear your report.

Comment: No, it didn't worked. It still says No Wifi Adapter after reboot

Comment: Are there any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep rtl`

Comment: As you posted this answer, I recieved a system update which fixed this Wifi problem. Probably linux recieved it's Wifi software from realtek. Thankyou